# Keep console up to wait for response

Tags: c#

I've got a console app.  I prompt the user for input...my code does its thing and at the end tries to print the output back to the user.

Here's how I try to post back the output to the same console window so they can see the results:

```
    Console.WriteLine( "Output: ");
    Console.WriteLine(resultMessage);
```

Problem is my console closes before it shows the resultMessage.

Comment: The console does show the resultsMessage, it just closes right after.

Comment: right, yea I got it to work with ReadLine().  Did not know there were so many options for this.

Comment: As others have suggested, adding a read after the output will cause the application to stop instead of exiting.  A clue to the user would also be appropriate, e.g. `Console.Write( "Press Enter to exit: " );`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Console.ReadKey(true);` it waits for any key press

Comment: +1, MSDN even recommends using `ReadKey` or `ReadLine` instead in the documentation for `Read`

Answer (score 1):

When you're in VS, you can also press `Ctrl` and `f5` to open your application outside of the debugger.

A consequence of doing so is that your window will stick around when your program is finished saying

`Press any key to continue`

Answer (score 0):

One more `Console.Read...`

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.Write("Press Enter to exit: ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think it will be better in case of using output redirection to file like 
`ConsoleApp.exe >results.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use Console.ReadKey(); after the output is written to the console.